# SET OPERATIONS IN ORACLE 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Is it possible to do SET OPERATIONS using more than one column in the SELECT clause?

For example:

```
SELECT NAME, AGE FROM tableA
MINUS
SELECT NAME, AGE from tableB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - [see the MINUS example](http://oreilly.com/catalog/mastorasql/chapter/ch07.html).

They operate on the column(s) in the SELECT clause, and require the ***data types***, not the column names, to match in order to work.